How to cache Cargo packages in the Github CI workflow?
I have a GitHub CI that uses a Cargo package. But each time, CI is run, it takes approx. 6 minutes to build the package. Is there a way to cache the binary so that on the next run, it does not have to build it again?
This is how my CI looks like.
name: "Verify the specs of concrete tests using bulloak"

on: "workflow_call"

jobs:
  bulloak-check:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: "Check out the repo"
        uses: "actions/checkout@v4"

      - name: "Install Rust"
        uses: "actions-rs/toolchain@v1"
        with:
          toolchain: "stable"

      - name: "Install bulloak or use the cached version"
        run: "cargo install bulloak"

      - name: "Verify the concrete tests"
        run: "bulloak check test/integration/concrete/**/**.tree --skip-modifiers"

      - name: "Bulloak summary"
        run: |
          echo "## Bulloak result" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "✅ Passed" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY


To cache Cargo packages in your CI pipeline, add the following job after installing Rust.
- name: "Cache cargo"
  id: cache-cargo
  uses: "actions/cache@v4"
  with:
    path: |
      ~/.cargo/bin/
      ~/.cargo/registry/index/
      ~/.cargo/registry/cache/
      ~/.cargo/git/db/
      target/
    save-always: true
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}
    restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-

This configuration caches the .cargo folder and the binaries at a location specified by the key ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}. When your Cargo lockfile changes, the cache will be updated with the new key, making sure that it only re-compiles when you update your package.
The full workflow would look like this:
name: "Verify the specs of concrete tests using bulloak"

on: "workflow_call"

jobs:
  bulloak-check:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: "Check out the repo"
        uses: "actions/checkout@v4"

      - name: "Install Rust"
        uses: "actions-rs/toolchain@v1"
        with:
          toolchain: "stable"

      - name: "Cache cargo"
        id: cache-cargo
        uses: "actions/cache@v4"
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.cargo/bin/
            ~/.cargo/registry/index/
            ~/.cargo/registry/cache/
            ~/.cargo/git/db/
            target/
          save-always: true
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-

      - name: "Install bulloak or use the cached version"
        if: steps.cache-cargo.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: "cargo install bulloak"

      - name: "Verify the concrete tests"
        run: "bulloak check test/integration/concrete/**/**.tree --skip-modifiers"

      - name: "Bulloak summary"
        run: |
          echo "## Bulloak result" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "✅ Passed" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY


Please add some text explaining what you have done. What did you change or add and why?

Thank you for the feedback @Jmb. I took your suggestion and updated my answer.
